# AngularJS 1.5 need to have checkbox set to be checked with model of objects without ng-checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Because of some other conflicts and dependencies , i'm not using angularjs 1.6.x ,  i'm using 1.5.x    so i'm not sure if there is some bug -  but I just know ng-checked is just awful

So I have `ng-repeat`

2 objects

1. vm.stateList contains all 50 states
2. vm.pager  contains json like object in which if a state WAS selected it WILL be in the list

Thus I'm looping through displaying all the states as checkboxes,  but I WANT to set them to be CHECKED  - if they are found in my vm.pager object

```
 div ng-repeat="states in vm.statesList"
```

checkbox I want checked if in my object

```
 <input ng-model="vm.pager.location[$index].state" type="checkbox" id="state{{states}}">{{states.name}}
```

Example of data

Notice that the `state` is found in the `location`

```
{
  "Id": 105,
  "Name": "blah",
  "Description": "other data",
  "$$hashKey": "object:98",
  "location": [
    {
      "Id": 96,
      "state": "NY",
      "Order": 9,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: few questions in my mind, this checkbox is in ng-repeat?
if there is any value in `location.state` you want to set to checked?

Comment: no value  ,  ... just the fact it exist... that it contains a value   number or letter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a function in your controller that is called from each checkbox:

```
<input ng-model="vm.pager.location[$index].state"
  type="checkbox" id="state{{states}}"
  checked="vm.isInState(states)">{{states.name}}

function isInState(state) {
  return vm.pager.findIndex((item) => item.location[0].state === state) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Is this a pretty normal  / typical thing to do  ?

Comment: It's standard to keep as much logic out of the template as you can, yes. The controller is best left to deal with that. It makes it cleaner to read for those who come along after you, and if you comment your controller well, easy to understand what it's trying to achieve.

Comment: how is this ` checkbox=...`  even recognizable as something that would get called?

Comment: Replaced checkbox with checked (typo)

Comment: I'm not sure that "checked" is actually going to call that function.   Perhaps you could provide a jsfiddle or code snippet